# Tightening Up line-height on an <a href> text

Tags: css

I have `<a>` tag inside a `<li>` that have text to make a hyperlink. When the text is too long, it wraps. I am trying to tighten the spacing between the lines of the wrap and cannot figure out a way to do it in CSS. I tried `line-height` but it has no effect on tightening it, only making it larger.
Anyone have an ideas?

Comment: I not sure whether this is possible, but if it is, it should be done using `line-height` in your CSS. So maybe decreasing this value would work? :)

Comment: set css to the <a> tag, float:left; or right and you can set the width as well

Comment: What values did you try for line height - if you use something between `0` and `1` it should tighten up the space as you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply have to set the `line-height` on the parent element and not on the `a` itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/jmQfr/

Comment: That was the issue. Needed to set it on the li and not the a Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` property is exactly what you describe.

Try specifying it like so: `line-height: 1;` or `line-height: .5;` - mind please that this property is supposed to shorten the distance between the lines *in the same* `a` or `li` element.